# Transformation of web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, web-config-transform

I work on a big asp.net entity framework web application with a lot of EDMX (actually 10, later, more than 30). Each EDMX has his own connection string.
When I deploy, my app, I want to change these connection strings. I can replace them with

```
xdt:Transform="Replace"
```

But that I need is to replace only a part of the attribut "connectionString".

If my connection string is :

```
      <add name="DemosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Demos.csdl|res://*/Demos.ssdl|res://*/Demos.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=user;Password=password;Home=OraClient11g_home1;Data Source=VDN131DEV15;Persist Security Info=True;ClientId=CLOEE2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I just want to replace VDN131DEV15 with another string on **all** my connection strings.

Possible with web.config transformation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Transform operation defined that will allow you to replace a part of the attribute value rather than the whole value.

I think you would need to write a custom build task to apply an xslt to the file in order to do what you want.